# inflating view vs inflating an element

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

I would like to *inflate* `R.id.catText`, but it doesn't ever show if I inflate it by itself. If I *inflate* `R.id.assets` (the container) then both elements show up just fine. I just don't want the container. How can I *inflate* `R.id.catText` without *inflating* `R.id.assets` ?

Also, can I *inflate* `R.id.catText` to an object? eg.

```
TextView catText = inflater.inflate(R.id.catText);
someView.addView(new catText());
```

my code:

```
LinearLayout myRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.assets);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assets, myRoot, false);
```

my style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:weightSum="1" 
 android:padding="50px" android:id="@+id/assets">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/catText" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ff0000"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LayoutInflater` works on `R.layout.*` only.  If you want to inflate just the `TextView`, you should put it in its own layout XML file.  If you need the container sometimes but not others, you can include the `TextView` in the container layout.

In catText.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/catText" 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
```

In the container xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:padding="50px"
    android:id="@+id/assets">
    <include layout="@layout/catText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can inflate whichever one you need.

Comment: I believe that answers this question, on to the next!

Answer (score 0):

Creating View objects from the XML layouts doesn't really need a inflate call. You should be using findViewByID for initializing Views, ie, TextView in this case.

Could you explain for what exactly you are trying to use an inflate call for the TextView?

Comment: I'd like to use the TextView multiple times. I'm just styling it in the xml and then want to use it in the app. Right now it's a loop.